# Go to the beginning of song list on iPod Nano 4th gen

Tags: music, ipod-nano, voiceover

I use an iPod Nano 4th gen. There are no playlists, just songs.

I am wondering how I can go back to the beginning of the songs list.
Reading this, I tried pressing the VoiceOver button, but it says "All songs", and neither the BACK <kbd><<</kbd> or PLAY/PAUSE <kbd>> ||</kbd> or VoiceOver buttons will start it from the beginning.

I have found that it is possible to restart from the beginning if I plug it on the computer to charge it and then unplug it, but I would like to be able to do this on the go.